# Porting `test` crate to a custom target?

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo

I have a [custom target file](https://github.com/CRust-OS/CRust-OS/blob/043c925d6c670c515babafe87e6d86ac5d399d2d/x86_64-unknown-xen.json) defined, and I'd like to run tests on it. Obviously, I'll need more than just `libcore` support, but I'm not sure exactly how much more.

When I run `cargo test --target x86_64-unknown-xen`, I get the following error message:

```
src/main.rs:1:1: 1:1 error: can't find crate for `test` [E0463]
```

This suggests that `cargo test` depends on some crate named `test`, and that I should port it to my target if I want to run `cargo test`. Such a crate does not exist on crates.io, nor is it documented on doc.rust-lang.org.

Comment: the `test` crate is part of Rust. But it depends on more things than just `libcore`. Have you considered running the tests on your host instead of your target?

Comment: @ker: Might be valuable to run the test on the target, to validate the correct integration of the runtime notably.

Comment: `cargo test` like `cargo run` will always run it locally. You'd need to manually compile it with `rustc` and then run the test binary on the target.

Comment: I am indeed trying to unit test my integration with the underlying platform. You're saying I should manually compile `test` and run a jury-rigged version of `cargo test`?